# Function to calculate average temperature from positive values of a list unless a temp >= the sentinel values if found in the list. Two parameters

Tags: python, list, function

calculate_average_positive_temperature() function that takes two parameters:

An integer list of temperatures called temperature_list.
An integer sentinel_value.

calculate and return the average of all the positive temperatures in temperature_list until a temperature greater than or equal to the sentinel_value is encountered.

-If a temperature that is greater than or equal to the sentinel_value is not found in temperature_list, then the average of all the positive temperatures in temperature_list should be returned.
-If there are no positive temperatures in temperature_list, or if the sentinel_value is met or exceeded prior to encountering a positive temperature, then the function should return 0.0 as the average temperature.
-A temperature of 0 should be counted as a positive temperature for the purposes of this function.
-Rounded to 2 decimal places

Comment: What approach(es) have you tried?

Comment: import math

def calculate_average_positive_temperature(temperature_list, sentinel_value):
    for i in temperature_list:
        if (i >= 0) and (i <= sentinal_value):
            return ((sum(i))/len(i))

Answer (score 0):

The required conditions are not clear enough for me, but from what I've gathered, here is what can work. Go ahead and add more if conditions as required. I've put what each condition does as comments as well in the code.

i) if no positive temperature or if all the temperatures exceed sentinel value, return 0.0

ii) if no value >= sentinal value, return average of positive temperatures

```
def calculate_average_positive_temperature(temp_list, sent_value):
    if max(temp_list) < 0 or min(temp_list) > sent_value: 
        return 0.0 # Returns 0 if no positive temp. or if no temp. is less than sentinel value

    elif max(temp_list) < sent_value:
        positive_temp_list = [temperature for temperature in temp_list if temperature >= 0]

        # returns average of positive temperatures if no temperature is greater than sentinel value
        return sum(positive_temp_list)/len(positive_temp_list)

x  = calculate_average_positive_temperature(temperature_list, sentinel_value)
print(x)
```